# Energy of harmonic maps from $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^2$ is quantized

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

> Assume that $U:\mathbb R^2\to S^2=\{y\in\mathbb R^3:|y|=1\}$ is a smooth solution of the equation $\Delta U+|\nabla U|^2U=0$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with $\int_{\mathbb R^2}|\nabla U|^2\,dx<+\infty$. Prove that
> $$\frac1{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb R^2}|\nabla U|^2\,dx\in\mathbb N_{\geq0}.\label{1}\tag{$*$}$$

This is a claim taken from [Juan Davila, Manuel Del Pino and Juncheng Wei's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-019-00908-y) (formula (1.5)). The paper refers to a proof using some ideas from geometry. I'm looking for an analytical proof of \eqref{1}.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an "analytical proof"? The "geometric" proof follows the following steps (A) Lift $U$ conformally to a smooth mapping $\phi: \mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{S}^2$. (B) Since $\phi$ is harmonic, it is holomorphic (or antiholomorphic) [due to Wood]. (C) For holomorphic functions the energy is determined by the topological degree. Steps (A) and (C) are basic computations, so it feels to me that what you are asking for is an "analytical proof" of Wood's result.

Comment: But there is a problem: the result is **necessarily** global. Lemaire [proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2042853) that if the domain is replaced by higher genus surfaces, there exists non-holomorphic harmonic maps into the sphere. So somewhere along the way the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{S}^2$) must creep in. So it is unclear to me what you are actually asking.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your comments! I want to seek a more PDE flavor proof, for example, using integration by parts, or using some functional analysis... I hope that there is a proof friendly to students who are not familiar with concepts like conformal mapping...  It doesn't matter if there is no such proof, I just wish there was. Regarding the authors, thank you very very much! I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: What exactly is $|\nabla U|$ for such a vector field?

Comment: @ChristianRemling: here $U(x,y) = (U_1(x,y), U_2(x,y), U_3(x,y))$ and $|\nabla U|^2 = \sum_{i} |\partial_x U_i|^2 + |\partial_y U_i|^2$.

Comment: By differentiating $U_1^2+U_2^2+U_3^2=1$ twice, we obtain $U\cdot\Delta U+|\nabla U|^2=0$ (for any function $U$), so the equation is only the extra condition that $\Delta U$ always points in the direction of $-U$.

Comment: If we try $U=(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi, 0)$ as a (toy) test case, then we're solving the equation if $\Delta \varphi=0$, and $|\nabla U|=|\nabla\varphi|$. I can't see any reason why the $L^2$ norm of this would be an integer, so I guess there's a (simple ?) reason why there are no harmonic functions with $\nabla\varphi\in L^2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for you comments! The fact that there are no harmonic functions with $\nabla \varphi\in L^2$ follows from: (1) If an $L^2$ function is harmonic in $\mathbb R^d$, then it is identically zero (by the mean value property and Hölder's inequality); (2) If $\varphi$ is harmonic, then $\nabla \varphi$ is also harmonic.